# Find all $(x,y)$ for which $f(x,y)$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2} &\text{ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$}\\1 &\text{ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$}\end{cases}$$

When I evaluate, using polar coordinates, $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{\rho \to0}1+\cos\theta\sin\theta$$ and therefore, the limit does not exist at $(0,0)$.

Knowing this, what would be my conclusion? What is the answer to the question? Would I say that it is continous at all points **other than** $(0,0)$?

Comment: "When I evaluate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2}$" That's not really the right way to put it as that limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your piece-wise function on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} $ is a rational function which is continuous everywhere except at  $(0,0)$ and the limit of this rational function at it approaches $(0,0)$ is not $1$. So it is continuous everywhere except at $(0,0)$ as you claimed.

Answer (score 1):

yes exactly it’s continuous with exclusion of (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct.

when $(x,y) \ne (0,0) $ the function is continuous as a composition of two continuous functions. for $(x,y)=(0,0)$ you found that the limit does not equal to zero so the function is not continuous on that point.